# Howto design NuGet package for HTML Helper Extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, package, nuget

I want to create a NuGet package to contain MVC3 Html helper extensions that I have written.  It would (or could) contain class, css, javascript and image files.  What would be the best way to package this?

- Can I make version that is a single compiled dll?
- If I make a source code version available, what folder structure would be best?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Nuget documentation for creating package via [command line](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) or [GUI](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages). It will generate the Nuspec file from your assembly.

As for folder structure, use the MVC structure already in place. `~/Content` for images and css, `~/Scripts` for javascript.

Comment: okay, that's pretty obvious.  I was wondering if there any sort of standard way that people try to "stay out of each others' way" when adding files like that.  But maybe not... maybe we just throw our files into the pile and hope for the best.

Comment: @Steve Brownell Keep your namespaces unique to other packages and you should be ok. Maybe your namespaces should all start with `SteveBrownell.HtmlHelpers`? But that's left up to you